# Воспроизвести звук при клике

Tags: swift, xcode

Хочу сделать такую вещь, как звук при клике
То есть, есть collection view 
И когда я кликаю на ячейку, чтобы был какой то звук( на счёт этого я так понимаю, что нужно заранее скачать звук, и вставить в программу )
Я пока только учусь и не очень себе представляю, как все это реализовать ?
Источники никакие не могу найти !
Можете помочь в данной ситуации ?

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем как проигрывать mp3 вызывайте `audioSessionConfiguration()`

```
// MARK: - Playback Text

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

fileprivate func playMp3() {
    if let mp3Url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "fileName", withExtension: "mp3")?.relativeString {
        if let stringUrl = URL(string: mp3Url) {
                audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: stringUrl)
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.volume = 1
                audioPlayer.play()
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func audioSessionConfiguration() {
        do {
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
            try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        }
        catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```